# What is this exterior wall feature?

Tags: exterior, trim, siding

What is the purpose of this horizontal feature around the perimeter of the building at about elbow height?
[image: exterior wall]

Is it purely aesthetic trim?

Does it add useful stiffening to the walls or have some other functional purpose?

If I need to run some utility such as a conduit or drainpipe vertically, should I cut a notch in this trim, or offset around it?

Comment: Seems odd.  People might have wanted to break up the look of plain wall or some needed repair to sliding, and decided to make the repair a design feature(make look good).

Comment: What's on the other side of the wall?

Comment: @jack Nothing obvious on the other side (though I haven't removed drywall to look). It extends all the way around the house at the same height.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility of a resident with mobility/balance issues?  Look at the wall in any hospital corridor...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it’s purely aesthetic. It’s called a “wainscot cap”. It’s more common on the interior. You can look it up on Google.

The portion of the wall below the cap is called wainscoting panel and is often painted slightly lighter or darker than the wall above, but always a complementary color.